# Why does on-screen video fail to update unless i have two queues?

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e \
    videotestsrc ! tee name=t0 \
    t0. ! queue ! x264enc ! matroskamux ! filesink location="test.mkv" \
    t0. ! queue ! queue ! autovideosink
```

Works, with both the file, and the on-screen display working

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e \
    videotestsrc ! tee name=t0 \
    t0. ! queue ! x264enc ! matroskamux ! filesink location="test.mkv" \
    t0. ! queue ! autovideosink
```

Does not work.

Here's another set of examples.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e \
    videotestsrc ! tee name=t0 \
    t0. ! queue ! autovideosink \
    t0. ! queue ! autovideosink
```

Works.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e \
    videotestsrc ! tee name=t0 \
    t0. ! queue ! autovideosink \
    t0. ! autovideosink
```

Doesn't. Why not? Why do both outputs from the tee need to be queues? At worst, I'd expect one autovideosink to work and the other to be blank, but instead one displays a single frame and the other is black.

But the following DOES work. What's going on?

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e \
    videotestsrc ! tee name=t0 \
    t0. ! queue ! autovideosink \
    t0. ! queue ! autovideosink \
    t0. ! autovideosink
```

Why does adding a third output negate the need for a queue on all of them?

```
gst-launch-1.0 --version
gst-launch-1.0 version 1.12.4
GStreamer 1.12.4
https://packages.gentoo.org/package/media-libs/gstreamer
```

Does anyone know why queue behaves like this?

This is the pipeline that I'm trying to make. The above are just minified examples.

(Note: the weird caps in the first line of the pipeline are to make sure my Logitech c920 camera outputs h264 instead of raw, and that my Logitech BRIO outputs video jpeg at 1080p, instead of raw at 720p. This has been tested, and works much better than simply "decodebin")

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
    v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-h264;image/jpeg;video/x-raw' ! decodebin ! 'video/x-raw' ! tee name=t0 \
    v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! 'video/x-h264;image/jpeg;video/x-raw' ! decodebin ! 'video/x-raw' ! tee name=t1 \
    v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! 'video/x-h264;image/jpeg;video/x-raw' ! decodebin ! 'video/x-raw' ! tee name=t2 \
    v4l2src device=/dev/video3 ! 'video/x-h264;image/jpeg;video/x-raw' ! decodebin ! 'video/x-raw' ! tee name=t3 \
    matroskamux name=mux \
    t0.  ! queue ! autovideoconvert ! x264enc ! mux. \
    t1.  ! queue ! autovideoconvert ! x264enc ! mux. \
    t2.  ! queue ! autovideoconvert ! x264enc ! mux. \
    t3.  ! queue ! autovideoconvert ! x264enc ! mux. \
    mux. ! queue ! filesink location="test.mkv" \
    videomixer name=mix \
        sink_0::zorder=1 sink_0::alpha=1.0 sink_0::ypos=0   sink_0::xpos=0    \
        sink_1::zorder=1 sink_1::alpha=1.0 sink_1::ypos=0   sink_1::xpos=960  \
        sink_2::zorder=1 sink_2::alpha=1.0 sink_2::ypos=540 sink_2::xpos=0    \
        sink_3::zorder=1 sink_3::alpha=1.0 sink_3::ypos=540 sink_3::xpos=960  \
    t0.  ! queue ! autovideoconvert ! video/x-raw, width=960, height=540 ! mix.sink_0 \
    t1.  ! queue ! autovideoconvert ! video/x-raw, width=960, height=540 ! mix.sink_1 \
    t2.  ! queue ! autovideoconvert ! video/x-raw, width=960, height=540 ! mix.sink_2 \
    t3.  ! queue ! autovideoconvert ! video/x-raw, width=960, height=540 ! mix.sink_3 \
    mix. ! queue ! autovideosink sync=false
```

---

---

---

This question was solved by adding max-size-bytes=0 max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=10000000000 to the queue.

For anyone not initiated into the gstreamer low level bits, this is *incredibly* counter-intuitive. But if it works it works, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about the concept of `PREROLLING` in GStreamer:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/design/preroll.html

> A sink element can only complete the state change to PAUSED after a
>   buffer has been queued on the input pad or pads.

What is not emphasized in the documentation is that the pipeline will only transition from `PAUSED` to `PLAYING` after all sinks have `PREROLLED`.

Also note that a `tee` is not threaded, so it is sequentially pushing samples downstream.

Here is what happens: sink 1 receives a sample, but will not start playing because it waits until all other sinks in the pipeline have received a sample so audio/video sync can be respected.

So now that sink 1 is waiting it is effectively blocking the `tee` preventing it from sending more data - in that case so sink 2. Since no data will ever reach sink 2 you are in a deadlock.

A queue will automatically add a thread in the pipeline path as a side effect - preventing the deadlock.

If you have only one queue it may actually work - depending in which order you connect your sinks to the tee. If the path with the queue is delivered first it won't deadlock and the tee can deliver data to the other one and the state change will be successful. (Same as the example with three sinks, if all paths have a queue but not the last you may get away with it)

It is good practice to use queues for all `tee` outputs.

The `x264enc` example is especially tricky. The problem you face here is that the encoder consumes too much data but not producing anything (yet) effectively stalling the pipeline.

Two ways to fix it:

1. use `tune=zerolatency` for the `x264enc` element
2. increase the buffer sizes in the queue of the non-encoder path to compensate for the encoder latency.

With `queue ! queue` you are actually doing case `2.` by doubling the buffer sizes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think that this is probably the answer to the why of the behavior I experienced, but I'm struggling to understand how this behavior isn't considered a bug. For example, in my case of 3 autovideosink elements, why don't I need a queue on the third sink?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. Reading comprehension fail. You said it's effectively a race-condition.

Comment: gst-launch-1.0 -v -e \
    videotestsrc ! tee name=t0 \
    t0. ! queue max-size-buffers=10000 min-threshold-buffers=10 ! x264enc ! matroskamux ! filesink location="test.mkv" \
    t0. ! queue max-size-buffers=10000 min-threshold-buffers=10 ! autovideosink

Doesn't fix the problem. With or without min-threshold-buffers, either 10 or 10000. Neither does adding a queue BEFORE the tee.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I also edited my initial question to contain the much more complex pipeline that I'm actually trying to use. The original examples were minimum-reproducibles.

Comment: You dont need min- buffer values. But the max values are defined by 3 different options. num-buffers, time and size in bytes. If you increase one another limit may be reached. Best is to set one to a value you want and other two to 0 to effectively disable them.

Comment: Thanks. I mean, that's an *incredibly* frustrating API, but at least now I know. Huge help!

Comment: It is a very flexible API. You can do a lot with it. But having much control over your pipelines also means you have to control a lot of things - sometimes. There is a learning curve but it all makes sense after some time! :)